# Making request timeout for a Spring REST API configurable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have REST APIs with bulk response which are getting timed out as the processing takes more than 120 seconds (default REST API request timeout). I looked into ways of changing this value and came to know that Spring has **spring.mvc.async.request-timeout** which can be set to desired value in application.properties. But I want this value to be externally configurable by the user. How can I make this value configurable ?

Comment: By setting that value on the command lie, environment property, external application.properties etc. Also this is for async requests if you are using blockig (regular) request than this property isn't going to work.